# How do I access payment field values in the woocommerce receipt function?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, payment-gateway

In my payment fields I have:

```
function payment_fields() {
      ?>
      <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <label><?php echo __("Card Number", 'centinel_pnp_majobytes') ?> 
             <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input class="input-text" style="width:180px;" type="text" size="16" maxlength="16" name="c3d_card_number" id="c3d_card_number" />
      </p>
      <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <label><?php echo __("Card CVV", 'centinel_pnp_majobytes') ?> 
             <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input class="input-text" style="width:180px;" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" id="c3d_cvv" name="c3d_cvv" />
      </p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <?php
}
```

In my process_payment function I'm able to access these variables; as an eg:

```
function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    //just an example
    echo "Card Number: ". $_POST['c3d_card_number'];
    echo "Year: ". $_POST['c3d_cvv'];
}
```

However I need to be able to access these variables on the receipt page to send of to a bank. These variables don't exist. Is there anyway I can do this? Current code:

```
public function __construct() {
    //other code...
    add_action('woocommerce_receipt_' . $this->id, array($this, 'receipt_page' ));
    //other code...
}

function receipt_page( $order ){
    echo "Card Number: ". $_POST['c3d_card_number'];
    echo "Year: ". $_POST['c3d_cvv'];
}
```

Result ends up being:

*Card Number: 
Year:*

How can I get access to these variables in the receipt function/page and if not how else could I pass these variables.

Comment: This is a good question... I am seeking the same info, namely a list of variables that can be used such as $invoiceid, $productid $productname, etc